# Unexpected token fi

Tags: linux, bash

```
#!/bin/bash
array=($1 $2 $3 $4)
if [ "$#" -ne 4 ]; then 
echo "Please enter Names"
else
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 
do 
echo "Welcome $i times"
done
echo "The Name is: "
fi
```

I'm getting syntax error in shell script: `Unexpected token fi`. Please guide what I am doing wrong in the script.

Comment: Probably something wrong with the original formatiing.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov It works for me, too. But I didn't change much in the edit.

Comment: I copied your formatted script still getting same syntax error.

Comment: May I ask you to copy here what exactly you do in your terminal? (Click [edit] and add that). Add `cat script_name` output and how you run it + the exact error message.

Comment: Error is resolved this time i used cat command to create a file previously i was using notepad++ to create a file.

Comment: @Omer Notepadd++ might have used Windows-style line endings, and bash then wouldn't recognize them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You script works for me, on `GNU bash, version 4.2.39`:

```
$ ./test A B C D
Welcome 1 times
Welcome 2 times
Welcome 3 times
Welcome 4 times
Welcome 5 times
The Name is:
```

```
$ cat test
#!/bin/bash
array=($1 $2 $3 $4)
if [ "$#" -ne 4 ]; then 
echo "Please enter Names"
else
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 
do 
echo "Welcome $i times"
done
echo "The Name is: "
fi
```

Comment: how can i get the bash version.

Comment: @Omer `bash --version`. (Note that you normally only accept an answer when your problem is solved.)

Comment: My bash version is GNU bash, version 3.00.15(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu).

Comment: As an aside, when you write a test script, don't call your script `test`, because it will clash with the shell builtin and you'll have to always remember to run it using the full path :)

Comment: @dogbane Thanks :) I only create such stuff in `/tmp` though.